# Почему на OpenServer сайт запускается частичо?

Tags: openserver

Привет друзья, есть такой вопрос, локальным сервером `OpenServer` пользуюсь уже не в первый раз, однако возникла такая трудность. При запуске сайта на локальном сервере, сайт открывается частично, стоит отметить что стили `CSS` все подгружены.
`.htaccess`прописал `redirect`, зашел в базу данных `mysql` изменил домэн, но безуспешно.

В чем причина? Из-за чего такое может быть и как такое исправить? Ребята помогите

Comment: Что значит "открывается частично"? Что именно не работает? Какая cms? Откуда переносился сайт? Что отображается в консоли браузера?

Comment: @Pyramidhead сайт открывается частично, не подгружается `header`, `img` а также вкладки, `CMS` - самописанная

Comment: Если сайт переносили, проверяйте в дампе базы все ссылки на прежний домен. Смотрите настройки в конфигурационных файлах cms